# How to recognize whether bash or dash is being used within a script?

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I'm writing a bash script and it throws an error when using "sh" command in Ubuntu (it seems it's not compatible with dash, I'm learning on this subject). So I would like to detect if dash is being used instead of bash to throw an error.

How can I detect it in a script context?. Is it even possible?

Comment: What you can do is to define the interpreter in the first line of your script: `#!/bin/bash` will make it be executed with `/bin/bash` when called with `./script.sh`. Also, good to see Pink Floyd around :)

Comment: `bash`'s features are a _superset_ of `dash`'s features; `dash` is smaller and faster, but is mostly limited to POSIX features - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell

Answer (score 15):

You can **check for the presence of shell-specific variables**:

For instance, `bash` defines `$BASH_VERSION`.
Since that variable won't be defined while running in `dash`, you can use it to make the distinction:

```sh
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && isBash=1
```

---

Afterthought: **If you wanted to avoid relying on variables** (which, conceivably, could be set incorrectly), you could try to **obtain the *ultimate* name of the shell executable** running your script, by determining the invoking executable and, if it is a symlink, following it to its (ultimate) target.

The **shell function `getTrueShellExeName()`** below does that; for instance, it would return `'dash'` on Ubuntu for a script run with `sh` (whether explicitly or via shebang `#!/bin/sh`), because `sh` is symlinked to `dash` there.

Note that the function's goal is twofold:

- **Be portable**:

  - Work with all POSIX-compatible (Bourne-like) shells,
  - across at least *most* platforms, with respect to what utilities and options are used - see caveats below.

- **Work in *all* invocation scenarios**:

  - sourced (whether from a login shell or not)
  - executed stand-alone, via the shebang line
  - executed by being passed as a filename argument to a shell executable
  - executed by having its contents piped via stdin to a shell executable

*Caveats*:

- On at least one platform - macOS - `sh` is NOT a symlink, even though it is effectively `bash`. There, the function would return `'sh'` in a script run with `sh`.
- The function uses `readlink`, which, while not mandated by POSIX, is present on *most* modern platforms - though *with differing syntax and features*. Therefore, using GNU `readlink`'s `-f` option to find a symlink's *ultimate* target is *not* an option.
  (The only modern platform I'm personally aware of that does *not* have a `readlink` utility is HP-UX - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114056/45375 for a recursive-readlink implementation that should work on *all* POSIX platforms.)
- The function uses the `which` utility (except in `zsh`, where it's a *builtin*), which, while not mandated by POSIX, is present on *most* modern platforms.
- Ideally, `ps -p $$ -o comm=` would be sufficient to determine the path of the executable underlying the process, but that doesn't work as intended when directly executing shell scripts with shebang lines on Linux, at least when using the `ps` implementation from the `procps-ng` package, as found on Ubuntu, for instance: there, such scripts report the *script's* file name rather than the underlying script *engine's*.<sup>Tip of the hat to [ferdymercury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7471760/ferdymercury) for his help.</sup>
  Therefore, the  content of special file `/proc/$$/cmdline` is parsed on Linux, whose first `NUL`-separated field contains the true executable path.

Example use of the function:

```sh
[ "$(getTrueShellExeName)" = 'bash' ] && isBash=1
```

Shell function `getTrueShellExeName()`:

```sh
getTrueShellExeName() {
  local trueExe nextTarget 2>/dev/null # ignore error in shells without `local`
  # Determine the shell executable filename.
  if [ -r /proc/$$/cmdline ]; then
    trueExe=$(cut -d '' -f1 /proc/$$/cmdline) || return 1
  else
    trueExe=$(ps -p $$ -o comm=) || return 1
  fi
  # Strip a leading "-", as added e.g. by macOS for login shells.
  [ "${trueExe#-}" = "$trueExe" ] || trueExe=${trueExe#-}
  # Determine full executable path.
  [ "${trueExe#/}" != "$trueExe" ] || trueExe=$([ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && which -p "$trueExe" || which "$trueExe")
  # If the executable is a symlink, resolve it to its *ultimate*
  # target.
  while nextTarget=$(readlink "$trueExe"); do trueExe=$nextTarget; done
  # Output the executable name only.
  printf '%s\n' "$(basename "$trueExe")"
}
```

Comment: You can use `readlink -f` to get the ultimate destination of a symlink, so in a sourced shell script (started with `. ./script`) one could use `BIN="$(readlink -f $0)"; BIN="${BIN##*/}"` to get the name of the shell without its path. In an executed script (started with `./script`) one would have to extract the shebang, and follow that for symlinks...

Comment: @zrajm: The purpose of my shell function is twofold: (a) be _portable_ and (b) work in _all_ invocation scenarios. I've updated my answer to clarify.
Your suggestion doesn't satisfy (a), because `readlink -f` is a GNU extension that doesn't work on OSX, for instance.
It doesn't satisfy (b), because analyzing the shebang line is insufficient - for instance, your script could have been passed as a direct argument to _any_ shell executable instead.

Comment: @zrajm: Furthermore, there is no simple, shell-neutral way that I know of to determine if a script is being _sourced_ (do tell me if you know a way).
Also, OSX, for instance, prepends `-` to the shell executable name reported in `$0` in a login shell (on OSX, all shells created in a terminal are login shells), so you'd have to account for that (that's the easy part).

Comment: Good idea, @ferdymercury - thanks; answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

Use $0 (that is the name of the executable of the shell being called).The command for example

```
echo $0
```

gives

```
/usr/bin/dash
```

for the dash and

```
/bin/bash
```

for a bash.The parameter substitution

```
${0##*/}
```

gives just 'dash' or 'bash'. This can be used in a test.

Comment: This isn't reliable. What if the script is executable and invoked as `./script`? What if the script is sourced?

Comment: $0 is set to an arbitrary string by whatever invokes the shell.  It's _almost_ always right...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach might be to test if a shell feature is available, for example to give an idea...

```
[[ 1 ]] 2>/dev/null && echo could be bash || echo not bash, maybe dash
```

Answer (score -1):

```
is_x_shell() { which ${1} >/dev/null && diff $(realpath /proc/$$/exe) $(which ${1}) >/dev/null; }

is_x_shell dash && echo is_dash
is_x_shell bash && echo is_bash
is_x_shell ash && echo is_ash
is_x_shell zsh && echo is_zsh
```

Answer (score -2):

```
echo $0 and [[ 1 ]] 2>/dev/null && echo
```

could be bash || echo not bash, maybe bash worked for me running Ubuntu 19.

Done slight Pascal, Fortran and C in school, but need to become fluent in shell script.